# Jenkins+Service Now integration

Tags: jenkins, devops, servicenow

Is there any way to integrate ServiceNow with Jenkins? I want to implement functionality in Jenkins to create an incident in ServiceNow.
Kindly help!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing official, but perhaps this add-on from ServiceNow Share can serve as a framework:

https://share.servicenow.com/app.do#/detailV2/b6e9ff7d13802200f609d6076144b0da/overview

Answer (score 0):

I have been developing a Jenkins plugin to integrate with ServiceNow through workflow steps. Check out the Github page:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/service-now-plugin

This plugins builds interactions with the [ServiceNow Table API](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-servicenow-platform/page/integrate/inbound_rest/concept/c_TableAPI.html)